# Execute SQL task with T-SQL query and with stored procedure in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis

In SSIS Execute SQL Task currently I am calling a stored procedure and inside the procedure I have a MERGE statement.

Is there any difference if I call that query (T-SQL MERGE) directly in the Execute SQL Task?
(are there any differences like Log will create if we used SP?)

Please reply me...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Stored procedure will provide you with a more maintainable solution as you will be able to leverage code reuse and there will be no need to change / re-release the package if your query logic changes

A stored procedure is also likely to provide you with the fastest execution time as it will be compiled and the execution plan will be reused on subsequent runs